# Passing the String value from one function to another without passing that string as a parameter

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I don't is this possible but what I am trying to do is passing the String from the one function to another function without passing that as a parameter.

In this code, the String result is already being pass through doInBackground, and I tried to do through calling the function but as there is a need of passing arguments, but I am not trying to figure out the one passing the value.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_convert);
    String first = "Hero";
    nameFor(first);
}

private String nameFor(String s){
    Log.i("name", s);
    return s;
}

private void loadInto(String result) throws JSONException {
    String check = nameFor(*****);
}
```

Through this code, I am trying to get is that String first in the loadInto function storing that value check. The String result already have a JSON object. Any help will be really appreciated, really stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable so both of these will work fine.

```java
  String a = "Hello Wrold!";
  String copy_of_a = new String(a);
```

```java
  String a = "Hello World!";
  String copy_of_a = a;
```

Comment: But it is on a different function. Initially, I declared String first as a global variable and tried to use on loadInto fuction but it shows a null length.

Comment: 1. You could create a copy before passing to function.
Or
2. You could create a copy in the first line of the function, do your stuff on the copied one and return the copied one at the end.